# Handling timers in java

Tags: java, timer

I have an application which runs a timer to check for idle time and once there is no activity for 10 seconds the application will close. I have nearly 100 screens and i want to track the inactivity seconds on all the screens. Its hard for me to write the handling events in all buttons, textboxes, labelboses one by one. What i have to do is add 10 seconds on every action of the user on the application. Even if it is mousemove add 10 seconds so tat the application wont close for another 10 seconds. Is there any way to handle this effectively ?

Comment: Close **everything** after 10 seconds of inactivity? That sounds like some terrible usability.

Comment: Have you tried using a [Mouse-Motion Listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html)?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: it sounds terrible but tats for security. Its hard to explain the whole application to you.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the following handler:

```
final Timer tm = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("10 SECONDS AND NOTHING HAPPENED");
    }
});
tm.start();
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {    
    @Override
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
        tm.restart();
    }
}, -1);
```

Comment: where do i havbe to add this block ? do i have to add this in all my windows or is it ok if i add this in my main() ?

Comment: @Deepak you only have to add it once.

Comment: when i use htis i am getting the error cannot find symbol
  symbol:   constructor Timer(int,<anonymous java.awt.event.ActionListener>)
  location: class java.util.Timer
--
(Alt-Enter shows hints)

Comment: @Deepak It's javax.swing.Timer

Comment: how do i kill this timer on the flow ? like i want to stop it when the user of the application decides not to close the application after 10 seconds inactivity. in that case i need to stop this timer. how do i do this ? when i try to call stop() method it says initialize the variable tm before calling tat method but the type of tm is final so hod do i initialize ?

Answer (score 3):

You could look into [Toolkit.addAWTEventListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#addAWTEventListener%28java.awt.event.AWTEventListener,%20long%29) this allows you to add a [MouseMotionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html) to react to mouse movements throughout your app and act accordingly.