# install timer component in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, timer

id like to install a timer component in netbeans much like the timer component for VB.net in visual studio but i can't seem to find one anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few components that cannot be added directly from the component pane of netbeans. Even i had the same problem when i had to work with the timers but there is no way for me to find one. So i started writing codes on my own. And its not hard to add timers into your application in code method as it does not need any location in the window. You just have to create a timer object and use it in your codes as simple as that. If you need to know how to create timers you can have a look at [swing timers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

--EDIT--
I dont have working example of swing timer but the code below shows the java util timer

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class timer_utility {
    public static void start_timer() {
        final Timer _iTimer;        
        _iTimer = new Timer(true);
        _iTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //timer task to be executed goes here.
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);         
    }
}
```

--EDIT--

Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777931/handling-timers-in-java)

Comment: @gasan: i always have trouble writing clean codes... even though i am not new to programming i still got to learn how to write proper codes.. i think it comes only by exp.. you can give me some tips if you wish to :) thanks!

Comment: if you don't have a code snippet (and are not inclinded to create one) that fits than simply than better not post _any_. Your description is good enough to get the OP started :-) BTW: when showing code examples in jave, please stick to java naming conventions!

Comment: @kleopatra: Thanks for that piece of advice :)